# base_url() not loading css file

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am trying to load a view from a controller file. If I reference my class in the view everything is fine, however if I reference a method from that  class my css does not load.

Here is a simple example:

Controller file:

```
<?php
class Example extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index ()
    {
        $this->load->view('myview');
    }
}
```

In the view file this works fine:

```
<li><a href="<?=base_url('example');?>">EXAMPLE</a></li>
```

But, this does not:

```
<li><a href="<?=base_url('example/index');?>">EXAMPLE</a></li>
```

I also tried to use the site_url() function but the result was the same.

Note: I have loaded the URL helper.

Answer (score 0):

Have you change your .htaccess file to remove index.php in url? then

```
<li><a href="<?=base_url('example/index');?>">EXAMPLE</a></li>
```

it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add

```
<base href="<?php echo cdn_url()?>" />
```

into the tag `<head></head>`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have configured your config to php file properly. Then See take a look and make sure that have you removed index.php from url? if yes then remove index from every url you are targeting.I Hope it will work.

Answer (score -1):

In config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/{your_project_folder}/';
```

Comment: Please add some information why this should fix the problem from the OP.